# How to change the default day of week and timestamp using date_trunc in snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a timestamp variable as input, and I want to group the data by week, with a week defined as being between saturday 21:00:00 and saturday 20:59:59. I am querying from a snowflake database.

My data looks like this:

```
employee_id  |   shift_started_at    |  hours_worked      
1            |   '2018-09-12 08:00:00' |  2     
2            |   '2018-09-10 22:00:00' |  8     
1            |   '2018-09-18 08:00:00' |  3
```

I am trying something like this:

```
alter session set week_start = 6;

SELECT dateadd('hour',21,date_trunc('week',shift_started_at)) as week_starts_at,
     min(shift_started_at) as first_shift_of_week,
     max(shift_started_at) as last_shift_of_week,
     sum(hours_worked)
FROM table
group by 1;
```

But even though this query gives me the right date for week_starts_at, the min and max select statements show that the group by statement is ignoring the dateadd function. In short, my weeks are being counted from midnight to midnight on saturday. Any advice on how to change the default timestamp used by date_trunc? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're applying `date_trunc(week..)` before adjusting the time by hours. One solution would be:

- first, move the shift times by 3 hours forward, so 9pm shift starts on Sunday midnight
- then truncate to a week, with Sunday being the first day of the week
- then move the result back 3 hours, to 21 on Saturday

Here's an example:

```
alter session set week_start = 7, timestamp_output_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS DY';
create or replace table x(t timestamp);
insert into x values('2018-09-14 08:00:00'),('2018-09-15 20:59:59'),('2018-09-15 21:00:00'),('2018-09-16 23:00:00'), ('2018-09-22 20:59:59'),('2018-09-22 21:00:00');
select t, dateadd(hour, 3, t), date_trunc(week, dateadd(hour, 3, t)), dateadd(hour, -3, date_trunc(week, dateadd(hour, 3, t))) from x;
-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
            T            |   DATEADD(HOUR, 3, T)   | DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, DATEADD(HOUR, 3, T)) | DATEADD(HOUR, -3, DATE_TRUNC(WEEK, DATEADD(HOUR, 3, T))) |
-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
 2018-09-14 08:00:00 Fri | 2018-09-14 11:00:00 Fri | 2018-09-09 00:00:00 Sun               | 2018-09-08 21:00:00 Sat                                  |
 2018-09-15 20:59:59 Sat | 2018-09-15 23:59:59 Sat | 2018-09-09 00:00:00 Sun               | 2018-09-08 21:00:00 Sat                                  |
 2018-09-15 21:00:00 Sat | 2018-09-16 00:00:00 Sun | 2018-09-16 00:00:00 Sun               | 2018-09-15 21:00:00 Sat                                  |
 2018-09-16 23:00:00 Sun | 2018-09-17 02:00:00 Mon | 2018-09-16 00:00:00 Sun               | 2018-09-15 21:00:00 Sat                                  |
 2018-09-22 20:59:59 Sat | 2018-09-22 23:59:59 Sat | 2018-09-16 00:00:00 Sun               | 2018-09-15 21:00:00 Sat                                  |
 2018-09-22 21:00:00 Sat | 2018-09-23 00:00:00 Sun | 2018-09-23 00:00:00 Sun               | 2018-09-22 21:00:00 Sat                                  |
-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The last column you can use for grouping, and things should work.